# Show Image after processing from python code in html page

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

cv2.imshow("preview", img)

This is my code sample which shows image "img" using imshow...But i want to show that image in a html page.How is this possible without flask and in easy way? Sorry if my question was not relevant since I am new to python.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest would be to save the image to some file locally and have an HTML file next to it that references the image. I.e.

```
# in your Python
cv2.imwrite("image.png", img)
```

And then the HTML file would be something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img src="image.png">
</body>
</html>
```